# Web Api post query

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

My English is bad, but I will try to explain

Model looks like

```
incidents -> accounts -> contacts

incident -> account, 1->M,
account -> contact , 1-> M.
```

Logic for add new Incident:

1. if account name is not in the system -> API must return 404 – NotFound
2. if contact is in the system (check by email) -> update contact record, link contact to account

If account NOT in system, all is ok (I get 404).

But, when account exists, I get duplicate exception, because I'm trying to add a new account with same name that already exists.

How can I solve this problem? If the account already sexist -> use this account and don't add new one.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Incident>> PostIncident(Incident incident)
{          
        foreach(var account in incident.Accounts)
        {
            bool accountexist = _context.Accounts.Any(x => x.Name == account.Name);

            if (!accountexist)
                return NotFound();
            
            foreach (var contact in account.Contacts)
            {
                var contactfromdb = _context.Contacts.Where(x => x.Email == contact.Email).FirstOrDefault();

                if (contactfromdb != null)
                {
                    contactfromdb.FirstName = contact.FirstName;
                    contactfromdb.LastName = contact.LastName;
                    contactfromdb.AccountId = account.Id;

                    _context.Contacts.Update(contactfromdb);
                    _context.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the JSON data being `POST`ed:

```
{  
  "description": "stringаа",
  "accounts": [
    {
      "name": "string3213",      
      "contacts": [
        {
          "firstName": "string",
          "lastName": "string",
          "email": "string231231"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create service layer. If you do not find a user, you should throw not found exception. if existing data comes, throws conflict exception etc.

I think you have problems about your project structure

Comment: You shouldn't use exceptions for control flow. Exceptions are quite expensive performance wise. Better is to check whether the resource exists and return the appropriate status code without throwing an exception.